# remove deleted object from associations without removing it in the database

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hbm

I have an entity called `DashboardPage` that contains a list of `DashboardPageItem`, when I try to run this code :

```
for(DashboardPage dp : dashboard.getPages()){
            if(dp.getIndex() == dashboardPage.getIndex()){
                dp.getDashboardPageItems().clear();
                Iterator<DashboardPageItem> itDashboardPageItem = dp.getDashboardPageItems().iterator();
                while (itDashboardPageItem.hasNext()) {
                   DashboardPageItem dpi = itDashboardPageItem.next();
                   itDashboardPageItem.remove();
                }

            }
        }
```

I get this error message :

```
deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [com.dashboard.entity.DashboardPage#22]
```

When I googled about similar problems, I find that I have to use `session.delete()` but this will remove the object from the database, and I only want to remove it from the list.

this is the hbm for my classes :

## DashboardPage:

```
<class name="DashboardPage" table="t_dashboard_page_dpa">
        <id name="id" column="dpa_id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id> 

        <property name="name" column="dpa_name"/>
        <property name="index" column="dpa_index"/>
        <property name="model" column="dpa_model"/>

        <many-to-one name="dashboard" 
                     column="fk_das_id"
                     foreign-key="das_id"
                     not-null="false"
                     lazy="false"/>

        <bag table="t_dashboard_page_item_dpi" name="dashboardPageItems" inverse="true" lazy="true" cascade="all,delete-orphan">
            <key column="fk_dpa_id" not-null="true" unique="false" foreign-key="dpa_id"/>
            <one-to-many class="com.lomaco.cloud.DashboardPageItem"></one-to-many>    
        </bag>


    </class>
```

## DashboardPageItem:

```
<class name="DashboardPageItem" table="t_dashboard_page_item_dpi">
        <id name="id" column="dpi_id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id> 

        <property name="position" column="dpi_position"/>

        <many-to-one name="dashboardPage" 
                     column="fk_dpa_id"
                     foreign-key="dpa_id"
                     not-null="false"
                     lazy="false"
                    cascade="all"/>

        <many-to-one name="widget" 
                     column="fk_wid_id"
                     foreign-key="wid_id"
                     not-null="false"
                     lazy="false"/>

    </class>
```

How can I solve this ?

## Edit :

this code is just a part from what I'm doing, so I don't want the database to be affected of the changes I make, but in another part I want to call the `session.save(dashboard)` which will save all the modification I made.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to cascade the deletion which was explicitly invoked by session.delete(), then instead of this:

```
cascade="all,delete-orphan"
```

Use only

```
cascade="all"
```

The delete-orphan cascade property works in a way that when you simply remove an item from a managed collection.. it is deleted at the end of the transaction.

Comment: In this case the delete won't work if I call session.saveOrUpdate(dashboard).

Comment: I see. Based on your post i though that you just want to remove it from memory not from database

Comment: yes, I'm trying to remove it from the list before I can save all the changes made to the `dashboard` object.

Comment: Just to be sure.. you get the error on this line - dp.getDashboardPageItems().clear(); ?

Comment: yes, when it tries to get `dp.getDashboardPageItems()`